# underscore return objects in primary key array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to use underscore to return a list of objects whose primary key is included in a given array of primary keys.

```
list = [object{pk: 1}, object{pk: 2}, object{pk: 3}]

primary_key_list = [1,2]
```

The function would return `[object{pk:1}, object{pk:2}]`

I'm having trouble finding a suitable one liner that can compare against a list of primary_keys

Comment: *"I'm having trouble finding a suitable one liner that can compare against a list of primary_keys"* I don't know what that means. Why does it need to be a one liner, and where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`_.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) (returns a subset of a collection given a predicate function):

```
_.filter(list, function(x) { return primary_key_list.indexOf(x.pk) > -1; });
```